# @WebServlet annotation seems to interfere with javadoc. Is there an easy workaround?

Tags: java, servlets, annotations, javadoc

I've just started using the `javadoc` tool to create documentation for a package containing a servlet class. It's working as expected for every class except the servlet, where the description doesn't appear.

After trial and error I narrowed down the cause to the `@WebServlet` annotation I use to declare the servlet for Tomcat. I'd rather not remove this annotation if it can be avoided. Is there an easy workaround that I could use?

This is the relevant section of my code:

```
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
@WebServlet("/MyServlet")

/**
* MyServlet description
*
* @author   ViscountRandom
* @since    2014-08-26
*/
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
...
```

The resulting `javadoc` page can be seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y87Xi.jpg) (note the description is missing and the `@WebServlet` annotation appears above the class name).

Thanks in advance for any help you can offer.

EDIT: I have tried repositioning the annotation in my code but that had no effect.

Comment: What about moving the javadoc above the annotation?

Comment: Oops. I should have mentioned that I tried that in my post. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @ViscountRandom this is a nasty bug! :-D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me, it seems to be working, see

```
/**
 * My javadoc
 * <br>25/08/2014
 */
@WebServlet
public class MyServlet {

}
```

generates

[image]

while

```
@WebServlet

/**
 * My javadoc
 * <br>25/08/2014
 */
public class MyServlet {

}
```

generates

[image]

I am using Java 7.

If you just want your javadoc to go right above the method declaration in the source code, you can still try

```
/**
 * My javadoc
 * <br>25/08/2014
 */
@WebServlet public class MyServlet {

}
```

which will generate

[image]

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed response. After examining your code, I realised the cause of my problem: I needed to separate the `import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;` statement and the `@WebServlet(...)` statement with the javadoc comment block (for some reason I moved the two statements together while trying to fix the problem, which isn't making much sense in the cold light of morning :) ).